# Suppress vector input for diag()

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I want to check if all diagonal elements of a matrix are zero and that the matrix is a square matrix in one line. Actually an easy task:

```
matrix = randn(5,5);
if all(diag(matrix)) && ~diff(size(matrix))
   result = true;
else
   result = false;
end
```

The problem is, my matrix can also be a 1-by-M- or N-by-1-vector. In that case `all(diag(vector))` returns a vector instad of just true or false. I don't like to have another `if...end` checking first if the input is 1D or 2D. Is there a way to overcome that issue?
Ideally `diag(V)` shouldn't create a diagonal matrix if V is a 1D-vector..

Comment: What's your expected output in this case? Can't you just swap your conditions over, then the `diag` condition will never even get checked unless the matrix is square

Comment: What wolfie describes is "short circuiting". the `&&` will not evaluate the second part if the first is false, because it knows the result will be false (that is the difference between `&` and `&&`)

Comment: What Wolfie said. The `&&` is a short-circuit operator. The stuff on its right is never evaluated if the stuff on the left is false. Alternatively, you can do `all(...,'all')` to always produce a scalar value. This syntax is new in R2018b.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the comments before posting the answer

Comment: Thanks guys, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, just write the condition for checking the square matrix first to trigger the [short-circuiting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html). i.e.

```
result = ~diff(size(matrix)) && all(diag(matrix));
```

That's it!